# Does file & registry redirection happen for offline installations?

Tags: redirect, filesystems, registry, syswow64

Does File and Registry **redirection** happen on registry hives and files of **offline windows installations**? Meaning that 32-bit programs see a different view of the filesystem / registry on a 64-bit systems even though it is not the running operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you're digging around on another disk whose operating system isn't running, you won't see file redirection